# how to enable opencart Seo Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, url-routing, opencart2.x

I am struggling with my open cart website from last 3 days. 
I am using opencart 2.3.0.2. Seo url option is not working for me. 
Below is the path for .htaccess file and opencart website file.

.htaccess path : /var/www/opencart/upload
application file : /var/www/opencart/upload

below is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried by updating RewriteBase with following options

```
RewriteBase /opencart/upload/
RewriteBase /upload/
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: needs more information: what is the docroot for your site? did you turn seo urls on in admin? has you set any keywords for urls in your store?

Comment: @billynoah Yes SEO URL is already set there and I have keywords for URLs.Can you tell me where i can find the docroot for site

Comment: docroot: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/opencart/upload

Comment: did you turn seo urls on in admin?

Comment: @billynoah  yes i have already told that is enabled

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable SEO URLs in the System Setting. Please see the below screenshot:
Go to System > Setting

1. Click **Edit** icon.
2. Click on the **Server Tab**.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thHs1.png)